# SQLITE printf only for non-null SELECT values

Tags: sql, sqlite, case, ifnull

| value | NameOfField |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SlNo |
| 10/3/21 | ManfDate |
| 2 | SlNo |
| NULL | ManfDate |
| 3 | SlNo |
| 11/3/21 | ManfDate |

My current sqlite query structure-

```
SELECT printf ("Item_No: %s Manufacturing_Date:%s ",(SELECT val from Orders WHERE name='Slno'),(SELECT val from Orders WHERE name='ManfDate')  )
```

This gives output-

```
Item_No:1    Manufacturing_Date:10/3/21
**Item_No:2  Manufacturing_Date:**
Item_no:3  Manufacturing_Date:11/3/21
```

I want to modify the sqlite printf statement such that the field name doesn't print when the corresponding value is null.i.e.

Output should look like-

```
Item_No:1     Manufacturing_Date:10/3/21
**Item_No:2**
Item_no:3      Manufacturing_Date:11/3/21
```

I have been trying this using IFNULL,IS NOT NULL, EXISTS,CASE etc but nothing seems to work for me. Will be thankful for any help

Comment: Look at the `coalesce()` or `ifnull()` functions.

Comment: Your query *should* return an error along the lines of "subquery returns more than one row" -- even if SQLIte doesn't return that error.  It seems strange that your query does anything useful at all.